# Create a different toolBars on different Fragments in one Activity

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

I have some task to create one activity whith includes two Fragments.On first Fragment include the simple toolBar with title and one custom button in the end(ImageView), on second I need button back,search with functional, and title.What is the best way implement this??Create toolBar in activity and change it dependent on the status or create toolbar in each Fragment??if someone already has such realization in code I will be grateful for his browsing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment(s), in `onCreate()` call `setHasOptionsMenu()` and implement the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Also see the '*Adding items to the Actionbar*' section of http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html